# How can I invoke mvn's dependency-get programmatically from Scala (or Java)?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-3

Let's suppose I have a `bash` command line that looks like this:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ -DgroupId=${GID} -DartifactId=${AID} -Dversion=${VERSION} -Dtransitive=false
```

I would like to do this from a Scala (or Java) program without involving the shell.  How could I do this?  Is there a Maven JAR or set of JARs with functions I could call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe take a look at https://github.com/coursier/coursier especially the API section, https://github.com/coursier/coursier#api

Comment: Wow.  Coursier looks very capable!